# Creating and validating at_hash with salt

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

When I'm creating an `at_hash` of an access token, should the hash be salted or not? If yes, how can it then be validated if the client does not know the salt that was used? The [specs](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#rfc.section.3.1.3.6) does not say much about it, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to store the salt as well. But "client", are you building a client/server application? If so then the client should never validate this, it should be the server that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the hash should not be salted. Remember that the `at_hash` binds the `access_token` to the `id_token` and protects it since the `id_token` is signed. The value of an `access_token` is quite different from a password where a salt is needed because it has less characters and is less random.